# Find the center and the radius of convergence for this complex series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} (z - \frac{1}{2}\pi)^{2n}$$

How do I know that the ratio test can be used here? Can it? How do I determine the method for solving this problem?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that the center is $\frac\pi2$?

Comment: In general, knowing wether the ratio test can be used is a result of simply trying it out. If it works, you can use it. If it doesn't, then you can't.

Answer (score 1):

For power series, it is usually either the root or ratio test. Factorials work much nicer with ratio test than the root test.